# How can I write this on Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

```
SELECT products.*  
FROM products
JOIN product_filters AS f1 ON f1.product_id=products.id
JOIN product_filters AS f2 ON f2.product_id=products.id
JOIN pro.. as f.. on f..product_id=products.id
WHERE ( f1.attribute_id=1 and f1.filter_id in (1,2) )
AND ( f2.attribute_id=3 and f2.filter_id in (6) )
AND (f...attribute_id=3 and f....filter_id in (6))
```

There should be a lot of attributes, so I needed to be able to add the same join?
Or is there a better option?

Comment: You probably need to look into associations on Sequelize. Check the following links:

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html


https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html

Comment: If you wish to join to the same table multiple times and an amount of times is determined   at runtime then you should add/remove associations (ProductFilter model) with unique aliases to the `Product` model on the fly